# select String only before special string

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my data column1 in table1

- "errorList":"017519033:**815**,","errorCode":"139"
- "errorList":"0115101233:**815**,","errorCode":"139"
- "errorList":"01815081233:**805**,","errorCode":"19"
- "errorList":"018995081233:**805**,","errorCode":"815"

i want to select data which contain 815 after ":" 
any idea how to do it?

my expected output :

- "errorList":"017519033:**815**,","errorCode":"139"
- "errorList":"0115101233:**815**,","errorCode":"139"

Comment: This is veeeerrry similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43407083/5089204)... Homework-Question? If yes, it is not fair to use SO as *do-my-job* platform!

Answer (score 0):

how about following

```
select * from table1 where column1 like 'errorList":"%:815%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Like` or `CharIndex`

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE column1 LIKE '%:815%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE charindex(':815', column1) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select * from mytable where column1 like '%:815,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table 
where 
right(errorList, len(errorlist) - charindex(':', errorlist)) = 815
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using XML for string-splitting:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('"errorList":"017519033:815,","errorCode":"139"')
,('"errorList":"0115101233:815,","errorCode":"139"')
,('"errorList":"01815081233:805,","errorCode":"19"')
,('"errorList":"018995081233:805,","errorCode":"815"');


SELECT *
FROM @tbl 
WHERE LEFT(CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourString,':','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('(/x)[3]','nvarchar(max)'),3)='815'
```

The biggest advantage of this approach is, that you can access any part of your string with an index, in many cases type-safe...

### UPDATE Check this out

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('"errorList":"017519033:815,","errorCode":"139"')
,('"errorList":"0115101233:815,","errorCode":"139"')
,('"errorList":"01815081233:805,","errorCode":"19"')
,('"errorList":"018995081233:805,","errorCode":"815"');

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,YourString
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(YourString,'"',''),':','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS TheXml
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT TheXml.value('(/x/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part1
      ,TheXml.value('(/x/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part2
      --,TheXml.value('(/x/text())[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part3
      ,Part3a AS Part3
      ,Part3b AS Part4
      ,TheXml.value('(/x/text())[4]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part5
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TheXml.value('(/x/text())[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part3
                  ,CHARINDEX(',',TheXml.value('(/x/text())[3]','nvarchar(max)')) AS PosComma) AS A
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEFT(Part3,A.PosComma-1) AS Part3a
                  ,SUBSTRING(Part3,A.PosComma+2,1000) AS Part3b) AS B
```

The result

```
Part1       Part2           Part3   Part4       Part5
errorList   017519033       815     errorCode   139
errorList   0115101233      815     errorCode   139
errorList   01815081233     805     errorCode   19
errorList   018995081233    805     errorCode   815
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where PATINDEX('%:815%',column1)>1
```